# Visual Studio Addin - Changing project references after project load without "really" changing them

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

So our build system and source control system is from Perforce, which is a piece of poopers.

We want to change reference to dlls in the project to some other location, for example, current reference might be C:\blah\debug\blah.dll, we want to change it d:\codeinjected\blah\debug\blah.dll

But we don't want to do this is the VStudio project file, because that is also our MSBuild build lab file, so is there a way to make an addin that can do it on the fly, without actually changing the references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you situationally want to change the location of reference DLL's for a Visual Studio project.  The easiest way to do this is to add condional constructs into the MsBuild file itself.

```
<Reference Condition="$(OnDevMachine)">
  ...
</Reference>
<Reference Condition="$(OnLabMachine)">
  ...
</Reference>
```

Another option is to have a common msbuild file for all of your projects.  In that particular project you can create a conditionally defined value pointing to the reference directory and have every leaf project reference that variable.  It will be less code and possibly more amenable to your build guy.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ReferenceDir Condition="$(OnDevMachine) == 'true'">Some\Dev\Path</ReferenceDir> 
  <ReferenceDir Condition="$(OnLabMachine) == 'true'">Some\Lab\Path</ReferenceDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Except, I can't bloat the csproj files, our build master suggested to ask on SO for other alternatives than this. Any ideas on how to potentially fake it while in the IDE?

Comment: The IDE uses the MsBuild files; this is the correct way to do what you want. I don't know why you/your "build master" deride it as "bloating" the files. It does no such thing. Surely your build system can handle a couple of additional lines.

Comment: @user986697 I added another possibility that will perhaps be more amenable to your build guy.  However i do feel like alterting the build file structure is the right approach here.  This is a build problem and should be solved by the build system. I've been on **many** teams which have taken similar approaches.